# Auto replace after pressing "ENTER" in VS CODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense, autocorrect

Im using `VS CODE` to write codes in `Lua` and sometimes when I typed some meaningful words like :

```
"false" , "true" , "else" , "end" , "break" and many others ...
```

after I press [Enter] to go to the next line , the the editor replaces the word that I typed with something else in `Lua` and The `Lua` plugins that I installed before...
for example when I type : `true`
and I press enter the editor replaces `getThisResource` which is from one of my plugins.
and every time after I typed a word , I have to press [Space] before going to The next line So that the word I wrote does not change.
does anyone know how to disable this option for all of the languages in `VS CODE`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out by myself.
The solution is to set the `Editor Accept Suggestions on Enter` to "off"
or add this Line in `Settings.json` :

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off"
```